# JQuery Selector for nested sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this node.

```
<figure class="wide">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/image_HDR.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img class="exif-reader" src="https://cdn.example.com/content_big_20171008_112106_HDR.jpg"">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        <div class="items">&nbsp;</div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I'm starting from the image using

```
var img = $("img[src$='value.FileName']");
```

I need to replace the HTML inside the `.items` div but I cannot find how to get it. In the page I have a lot of nodes with this structure. I need to select the `.items` div that is inside the same node of the `img`

Comment: img.closest(".wide").find('.items');

Answer (score 0):

With css it's hard, but jquery makes it fairly easy I think:

```
var items = $("img[src$='value.FileName']").closest('figure').find('.items');
items.html('<p>blabla</p>');
```

Comment: The image selector is the example from your code so it may not work. on `closest` and `find` I am dead certain that is proper use for your html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet example using your code:

```js
$(function(){
  var $img = $(".exif-reader");
  
  var $itemsDiv = $img.closest(".wide").find('.items');
  
  $itemsDiv.html("enter html here")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure class="wide">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/image_HDR.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img class="exif-reader" src="https://cdn.example.com/content_big_20171008_112106_HDR.jpg"">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        <div class="items">&nbsp;</div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I changed the img selector since $("img[src$='value.FileName']"); was not working in a snippet for me.